# How to Iterate through all Files then all lines in a Directory in Bash?

Tags: bash, csv

I have a directory, /mnt/c/temp/, that is full of CSV files that I'm trying to run a script within that will parse filenames and file contents to create a new file.

All files within /mnt/c/temp/ have a similar naming structure: File_2022_01_01.csv,File_2022_01_02.csv, etc..

The contents of the files are irregular but contain a column that I am trying to pull out called "Target".

The end goal of the script would be for each file pull out the name and assign that to a variable. Then for each row in the file pull out the Target column value, then append the Date and Target variable values to TargetFile.csv

I have a framework that I've gotten set but I'm having trouble with iterating through the contents and assigning variables in turn.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for filename in /mnt/c/temp/*; do

#Below is to extract the date from the filename and assign to variable. 
 VarDate=$(echo `basename "$filename"`|grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}')                                                                                                                                            

#Below parses the column number for the Target column and assigns to variable. 
TargetColumn=$(awk -F ',' -v col='"employeeID"' 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==col) {print i;exit}}' $filename) 

#Below is to grab the line values in the file for the Target column.
TargetValue=$(awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $TargetColumn}' $filename)

#Below is to append the Date and Target Values to the destination 
echo $VarDate ','  $TargetValue >> TargetFile.csv

done;
```

Currently I'm having trouble with the TargetValue as it looks to be producing the entire contents of the file instead of the given column which is then messing up with my append statement.

I would very much appreciate any advice or guidance on how to properly produce the expected outputs.

Comment: Paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net and make the recommended changes.

Comment: Thank you @j_b , I wasn't aware of this resource and I'll be using it going forward. I've updated my code per the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing a CSV might require specialized tools but, assuming that you can split the fields accurately on **each** comma, then you could write an `awk` for processing all the files in a single call:

```bash
awk -v colName='"employeeID"' '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
    FNR == 1 {
        for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ )
            if ( $i == colName )
                colNum = i
        match(FILENAME, /[0-9]{4}([_-][0-9]{2}){2}/)
        fileDate = substr(FILENAME, RSTART, RLENGTH)
        next
    }
    { print fileDate, $colNum }
' /mnt/c/temp/* > TargetFile.csv
```

---

If the CSVs require a real parser then I would recommend [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (available [here](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases) for several OSs) for this task:

```bash
mlr --csv --ho put '
    FNR == 1 { @date = regextract(FILENAME,"[0-9]{4}([_-][0-9]{2}){2}") }
    $* = {1:@date,2:$employeeID}
' /mnt/c/temp/* > TargetFile.csv
```

Comment: Thank you and much appreciated! There was a bit of jankiness to workout as my data had a few extraneous commas in them, but this performed the expected operation perfectly and performantly.

Comment: Just as a followup, would it be possible to get some guidance in regards to the iterative steps of your code? There are parts I can understand on a general level but how it cohesively connects and works is outside of my understanding. I'd love to figure out the tricks to be able to reproduce my own design. Best regards!

Comment: @SomekindaRazzmatazz `FNR == 1` is true for the first line of each file (which corresponds to the CSV header), and in the associated block of code: **1)** you loop through each field for finding the index of the `employeeID` column; **2)** you extract the date from the current filename. Then, for all the other lines you just have to print the previously determined date and column.